# Taylor series cos third order

Tags: series-expansion

I need some help to develop the Taylor series on the following:
With the signals:

```
x1(t)=A1Cos(w1t)

x2(t)=A2Cos(w2t)

x3(t)=A3Cos(w3t)
```

and a system

```
y(t)=k1x(t)+k3x3(t)
```

and considerint this

```
x(t)=x1(t)+x2(t)+x3(t)
```

I have to develop the Taylor series and I started developing but I think I'm missing many parts. Please, can you help me?

[image]

Comment: In-built function names should start with Upper case. Here Cos. Function definition using := Please refer to documentation on Functions & Series. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/DefiningFunctions.html and  http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Series.html

Comment: The formula is incorrect: unbalanced braces and new variable ($\omega$ without an index).

Comment: Please include working mathematica code.

Comment: I'm doing it by hand, sorry

Comment: See my answer and use it as a template in order to put in your question specific mathematica code. Also try to explain more clearly (from mathematical point of view) what you want to do.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, according to the OP's comment, it is not about [Mathematica](http://wri.com).

Answer (score 4):

Not sure about you are asking.
Consider reformulate your question and certainly put some Mathematica code.
You can you use as a template the input below:

```
x1[t_,w1_] := A1 Cos[w1 t]

x2[t_,w2_] := A2 Cos[w2 t]

x3[t_,w3_] := A3 Cos[w3 t]

  (*This is the standard way to define functions in Mathematica. Note that 
    the arguments are included within brackets and not parentheses, note  
    also the underscore and the semicolon. Contrary to other languages you 
   can ommit the symbol of multiplication; use a space instead.*)
```

Then, for instance,

```
y[t_, w1_, w2_, w3_] = 
 k1 x1[t, w1] + k2 x2[t, w2] + k3 x3[t, w3]
(* A1 k1 Cos[t w1] + A2 k2 Cos[t w2] + A3 k3 Cos[t w3] *)

Series[y[t, w1, w2, w3], {t, 0, 5}]
(* SeriesData[t, 0, {
 A1 k1 + A2 k2 + A3 k3, 0, 
  Rational[1, 2] (-A1 k1 w1^2 - A2 k2 w2^2 - A3 k3 w3^2), 0, 
  Rational[1, 24] (A1 k1 w1^4 + A2 k2 w2^4 + A3 k3 w3^4)}, 0, 6, 1] *)
```

Comment: Thank @dimitris. I'll use your answer as a template

Comment: You are welcome:-)!

Comment: Sorry but now I am more puzzled:-)! You completely change your question. And now my answer appears like "out of space".

Answer (score 0):

I leave the first answer as it is. May be it is still useful for you. 
But I think you will not avoid the "closing" of the question.

http://mathematica.stackexchange.com

is an an amazing site but you cannot learn the very basics of Mathematica
syntax from it. It's not its purpose.

Just googling with keywords like: basic mathematica, mathematica intro, beginner's mathematica etc

http://www.pa.msu.edu/~duxbury/MathemIntro.html
http://www.singacom.uva.es/~fhernando/Lecture%20Notes/2%20Basic%20calculations.pdf
https://pantherfile.uwm.edu/sorbello/www/classes/mathematica_primer.pdf

In any case I post a new reply more relevant to the new query (I hope:-)!). Still it is not clear what you are looking about.

Let

```
eq1 = (B Cos[x])^3 == 1/4 (3 B^3 Cos[x] + B^3 Cos[3 x]);
```

Then you can use `Reduce` in order to solve it for `x`.

```
Reduce[eq1, x]
(* (C[1] ∈ Integers && x == π + 2 π C[1]) || 
 B == 0 || (-π + x)/(2 π) ∉ Integers *)
```

Then substitute x to

```
eq2 = Cos[x] + Cos[y] == 2 Cos[x/2 + y/2] Cos[x/2 - y/2];
```

and solve it in the same way for `y`.

Lastly, do the substitutions in the third equation

```
k(A Cos[x]+B Cos[y]+C Cos[z])^3
```

via `expression/.{x->...,y->...}`.

Hope that this helps.

Comment: I forgot to mention wolfram's own intro http://www.wolfram.com/broadcast/screencasts/handsonstart/

Comment: Now after the new editing it is the second reply that seems irrelevant:-!)

Comment: Thanks again @dimitris, very helpful. In fact, I'm looking for a cos(2A-B) ... type expression. BTW, I don't know what happen with my new edition of the question..